# Unit testing, when intercepting requests using Filter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I'm tring to restrict the number of requests to our server. I'm using Spring Boot and use Filter and doFilter but I'm having difficulties writing unit tests.

```
@Component
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

  @Value("${chatGPT.max.request.per.second}")
  private int MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND;

  private final LoadingCache<String, Integer> requestCountsPerIpAddress;

  public RequestFilter() {
    super();
    requestCountsPerIpAddress = Caffeine.newBuilder().
        expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build(key -> 0);
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    var httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    var clientIpAddress = getClientIP((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    if(isMaximumRequestsPerSecondExceeded(clientIpAddress)) {
      httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value());
      httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("Too many requests");
      return;
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
  }

  // RequestFilterMaxRequestExceededTest
  public boolean isMaximumRequestsPerSecondExceeded(String clientIpAddress){
    boolean max_request_exceeded = true;
    var requests = requestCountsPerIpAddress.get(clientIpAddress);
    if(Objects.isNull(requests)) {
      // if there are no requests tracked yet, requests to be initialized
      requests = 0;
    }
    if(requests > MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND) {
        return max_request_exceeded;
    }
    requests++;
    requestCountsPerIpAddress.put(clientIpAddress, requests);
    return !max_request_exceeded;
  }

  public String getClientIP(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String xfHeader = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (xfHeader == null){
      return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return xfHeader.split(",")[0];
  }

}
```

I try to mock the call of this method

```
    var requests = requestCountsPerIpAddress.get(clientIpAddress);
```

Are there any ideas? And I tried all options already.

I tryed to use @Mock, I tried to mock Filter class.

I want this block to be true:

```
@DisplayName("---")
  @Test
  void requestFilterMaxRequestExceededTest() {
    for (int i=1; i < 12; i++) {
      when(filter.requestCountsPerIpAddress.get(clientIpAddress)).thenReturn(i);
      if (i>9) {
        assertThat(filter.isMaximumRequestsPerSecondExceeded("testIp"))
            .isTrue();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock the class you want to test but need to actually create it. You would need to:

- add a value for `chatGPT.max.request.per.second` in your test/resources/application.yml (or properties) then change your test to
- `@Autowired` the filter class
- `@Mock`the `ServletRequest`, `ServletResponse` and `FilterChain`
- configure the request with `when(servletRequest)` as needed for the headers
- change your test to call filter.doFilter 12 times
- check the ServletResponse